# textbox.Text=stack.Pop() не работает

Tags: c#, стек

Каким образом работает stack.pop() ?
Хочу реализовать функцию Undo

Записую в Stack текст с формы при изменении текста

```
private void Output_tb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    undoActions.Push(output_tb.Text);
}
```

Здесь возвращаю текст при нажатии кнопки Undo

```
private void Undo_bt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (undoActions.Count<1)
        {
            return;
        }

        output_tb.Text = undoActions.Pop();
```

Но прежнее состояние текста появляется только при втором нажатии на кнопку Undo. Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 3):

потому что последнее значение в стэке, такое же, как текущее значение в текстбоксе

```
if (output_tb.Text != undoActions.Peek())
  undoActions.Push(output_tb.Text);
```

Comment: я использовал в точности такую реализацию Undo, только для события KeyDown в output_tb - и отлично - удалялся один символ, но мне нужно реализовать Undo на случай, если текст будет не введен с клавиатуры а вставлен или сгенерирован. Попытался через TextChanged, не получается

Comment: Попробовал ваш ответ, компилятор сказал, что стэк пустой, я в конструкторе MainForm добавил undoAction.Push(""); , но все равно после этого нет результата.